# How can we check the page/resource "last modified by" activity in Magnolia?

Tags: magnolia

How can we check the page or resource last modified by particular user? I mean, Can we add the following item for resources,Assets and Pages apps?

[image: Add last modified]

Thanks,
Vijay Kodali.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a new column (e.g. `modifiedBy`) in your contentView, i.e. in `/modules/[path-to-your-subapp]/workbench/contentViews/list/columns` with `mgnl:lastModifiedBy` value in `propertyName` property:

[image]